# Not able to understand and map output of /proc/net/tcp

Tags: 12.04, networking, proc

The output of /proc/net/tcp on my ubuntu 12.10 is the following:

```
sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 0100007F:0CEA 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   115        0 14759 **1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 -1**
```

so as we can see that the number of data columns displayed are more then the names of the columns. So if I see in the end, I can find the following:

`uid ->115`

`timeout->0`

`inode->14759`

can some one tell what are the values after inode column, i.e. `1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 -1`

Answer (score 5):

It's detailed in CPANs [Linux::Proc::Net::TCP](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Linux-Proc-Net-TCP-0.05/lib/Linux/Proc/Net/TCP.pm) module page:

```
 1000        0 54165785 4 cd1e6040 25 4 27 3 -1
    |        |    |     |    |     |  | |  |  |--> slow start size threshold, 
    |        |    |     |    |     |  | |  |      or -1 if the threshold
    |        |    |     |    |     |  | |  |      is >= 0xFFFF
    |        |    |     |    |     |  | |  |----> sending congestion window
    |        |    |     |    |     |  | |-------> (ack.quick<<1)|ack.pingpong
    |        |    |     |    |     |  |---------> Predicted tick of soft clock
    |        |    |     |    |     |              (delayed ACK control data)
    |        |    |     |    |     |------------> retransmit timeout
    |        |    |     |    |------------------> location of socket in memory
    |        |    |     |-----------------------> socket reference count
    |        |    |-----------------------------> inode
    |        |----------------------------------> unanswered 0-window probes
    |---------------------------------------------> uid
```

Comment: The perl docs themselves are just an excerpt from the [kernel documentatin](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/proc_net_tcp.txt) on this topic

Comment: The link is broken. Please update it.